# Upload .csv to postgresql database - Datagrip vs. DbVisualizer

Tags: postgresql, csv

All, I have extensively researched this, and spoken with our Database admin/CTO and we've done our best to solve before posting.

I want to upload .csv data to a postgresql table (call it my_table)

I have the following grants for it:

DELETE,
INSERT,
SELECT,
TRUNCATE,
UPDATE,

The upload works great with DbVisualizer Pro (I have a trial version), but Datagrip (which I paid for) says I need to be the Table Owner (which creates problems elsewhere = above my pay grade)

What am I missing? I get the same result whether I use the GUI or write an UPDATE query

ERROR: must be owner of relation my_table.
[42501] ERROR: must be owner of relation my_table

Comment: How are you trying to upload the data?

Comment: If you paid for Datagrip, then why don't you ask that with the Datagrip support?

Comment: Support has been very helpful, but ultimately hasn't been able to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off *Disable Indices and Triggers, Lock table (may be faster)*

[image]